# View OneDrive document in WebView2

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, webview2

I can upload a file to OneDrive without logging each time using a refresh token to get an access token and this works well.

Once the file is uploaded I want to view (and edit in the future) it in our windows application in a WebView2 control.  But navigating to the webURL passed back in the upload response prompts for a log in.

How do I navigate to a driveItem webURL in a WebView2 control using the refreshToken so the user is not prompted to log in?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: So I have achieved this by using the createLink call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but I would be interested to know if this is the best way? Or how have others done it?